# Magento 2 : Files responsible for magento checkout process

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, language

[image]

I'm using a german translation pack but it doesn't translate everything in the **Shipping Method Section** (in Checkout Process). Which files are responsible for rendering out this section ? I want to change the strings in the Code manually

Comment: You can check files path hint, like this [printscreen](https://goo.gl/0xQOo2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the file for shipping methods is rendered from here `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`, however the title of it is an admin configuration setting.

To change the method/carrier title you need to go to `Stores - Configuration - Sales - Shipping Methods`, select the shipping method you use and there should be two fields that says "Title" and "Method Name".

Note: If you're using multi stores make sure to change the scope of the store you want to do changes.